# Query extremely slow when joining 2 views

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I will preface this by saying i am not a DBA, just a dev that is trying to figure out performance problems with the following query we have.

```
 SELECT
        OCCoverID as StaffID, FullName, SUM(OCWeight) AS Num
    FROM vuOCStaffAbsentExpandedMini
        INNER JOIN vuStaff ON OCCoverID = StaffID
    WHERE
        SADate = '2019-10-4'
        AND MIDent = 506
        AND SASupplyID IS NULL
        AND CoverStaffSupplyID IS NULL
        AND StaffMIDent <> 1
    GROUP BY
        OCCoverID, FullName
```

It takes about 1 minute to execute every time, we have double checked (we think) all required indexes, ran it through index tuner and still same issues.
Below is the actual plan that it creates.

Any help would be appreciated, we are using sql server 2012 express

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJgOtXHur

Comment: estimated vs actual rows for the table spool is substantial - 1589 vs 86 million. Check your views.

Comment: How many levels of `VIEW`s are there? Are all the datatypes on `JOIN`ed fields **identical**? Could you please provide the DDL for your views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a performance spool that feeds your nested loops operator (non-apply)

...with very low estimates.

[image]

Now, for each value in the top(outer) input, the table spool will produce a rebind. No rewinds are possible for performance spools on non apply nested loop joins.

> ...The lazy table spool is populated once during the first loop
>   iteration. The spool rewinds its contents for each subsequent
>   iteration of the join. With nested loops join, the inner side of the
>   join is a static set of rows because the join predicate is on the join
>   itself. The static inner-side row set can therefore be cached and
>   reused multiple times via the spool. A nested loops join performance
>   spool never rebinds....

[Source: Paul White on Nested Loops Joins and Performance Spool](https://sqlperformance.com/2019/09/sql-performance/nested-loops-joins-performance-spools)

The low estimates result into the actual situation below:

[image]

You can validate the high rowcount of the spool output by multiplying both inputs (of the compute scalar & the stream aggregate).

`515 728` (outer input) `* 168` (inner input) = `86 642 304`

---

**Solutions**

The first thing to fix would be fixing why the estimates are so low.

You could try updating the statistics of the table referenced in the view.

**But** it appears that you are doing a `LIKE` comparison between `dbo.TblOnCall` and the tables feeding the spool operator.

[image]

That can also be seen on the NL operator that gets the data from the spool.

[image]

(`EXPR 1137` = the outer input, `UNION` = the inner input).

**For a longterm solution**,

I would fix this `LIKE` comparison and any other parts that will impact your estimations gravely.

We would have to see the views to give the most correct query recommendations.

**For a temporary quick fix**, you can disable the spool with a trace flag or a query hint.

> Performance spools can be disabled with lightly-documented trace flag
>   8690, or the documented query hint NO_PERFORMANCE_SPOOL on SQL Server
>   2016 or later.
>   [Source](https://sqlperformance.com/2019/09/sql-performance/nested-loops-joins-performance-spools)

An example of implementing this is running

`DBCC TRACEON(8690,-1)` *(will be removed on instance restart)*

Or better, running the query with `OPTION(QUERYTRACEON 8690)`

```
 SELECT
        OCCoverID as StaffID, FullName, SUM(OCWeight) AS Num
    FROM vuOCStaffAbsentExpandedMini
        INNER JOIN vuStaff ON OCCoverID = StaffID
    WHERE
        SADate = '2019-10-4'
        AND MIDent = 506
        AND SASupplyID IS NULL
        AND CoverStaffSupplyID IS NULL
        AND StaffMIDent <> 1
    GROUP BY
        OCCoverID, FullName
OPTION(QUERYTRACEON 8690);
```

Comment: seems like the hint sort of fixed the query to be better performant but ultimately the updating of the db stats fixed it all, thank you